# CPU High temperatures 12.04

Tags: cpu, overheating

Hi I have a Acer Aspire 4530 With a AMD Athlon(tm) X2 Dual-Core QL-62 × 2  prossesor. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now my laptops temperatures are realy high specially when using flash.
This is one of my temperature readings Ive had higher temperatures than this
cpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +80.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +79.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)

Anything I could do to fix this?

Comment: Even I have the same problem; but the CPU consumption problem is with flash and not with Ubuntu, per se. I had the same issue with previous versions of Ubuntu. As soon as you start a flash video, the CPU consumption and consequently the temperatures soar up.

Comment: Flash is buggy is CPU costing , if your temp is ok when flash is not active , that's not ubuntu's problem

Comment: Update the Kernel. This can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happaned to me months ago. It was a faulty CPU. Every time I used flash the CPU went +90% and temp up to 100C and triggered thermal shutdown. I still don't know if it was a faulty sensor or an over stressed CPU after years of gaming (lol).

Keep in mind that usually AMD CPUs should be at or below 70C or they will start causing errors, even if they can go all the way up to 105C the north bridge will power down the computer at 100C stopping all fans and/or cooling systems immediately and this event could damage your components.

I fixed my problem changing the CPU.

Comment: the CPU does heat up but the thing that mostly Makes me worry is the PCI adapter temperature that is to high sometimes even more hot than CPU

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that this is Ubuntu's fault. I upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04. The moment I did that my minimal core temperature started from 60 oC. When playing flash videos it might get up to 80-85 oC. Under Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 I have/had no such problems at all. Power management is still something that is left behind by Canonical in the new Ubuntu release. It was never good and it'll probably stay like this for some time.